# Can I return to the 12th Floor of Augusta Tower?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

I'm working on the mission in *Final Fantasy XIII-2* which requires you to bring fully explored maps to someone in Academia -400 AF-.

Sometime after exploring all I could of Augusta Tower -200 AF-, I noticed I acquired a Key Item called **Access Key 13**. Using this key to explore the 13th Floor of Augusta Tower -300 AF-, I was able to reach 99% map completion.

Much to my dismay, I discovered a sliver of unexplored area on the 12th Floor. The problem is, when I try to use the elevator to head down there, I get the message, "Access key 13 confirmed," and it sends me to the 13th Floor. If I try from there, I get the same message and am sent *back* to the 15th Floor.

**Can I ever return to the 12th Floor, or is the completionist in me doomed to cry a little?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually reachable right now, you don't have to close the gate to reach the 12th floor.

1. Go to the 15th floor
2. Take the mini elevator from the 15th down to the 14th
3. Then take the big elevator in the middle down to the 12th.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can still return to the 12th floor later in the game.

From the top of my head you have to close the gate to be able to get to the 12th floor again.